# How to sort a 3-dimensional array by a key in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

This is an example of an array that I am trying to sort by the key `match_points` (descending):

Let the array printed below be called `$my_arr`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [109] => 92
                    [match_points] => 50
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [16] => 12
                    [match_points] => 62
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [80] => 51
                    [match_points] => 63
                )

        )

)
```

I tried this:

```
$a = usort($my_arr, 
    function (array $a, array $b) { 
        return $a["match_points"] - $b["match_points"]; 
    }
);
```

But I am getting this warning message:

> Undefined index: match_points

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php) did not explicitly show how to sort a 3 dimensional array by a specific key,
although the answer can be *inferred* after reading that post.

Comment: You have one more array dimension inside each array! Use `var_dump` to see what you're working with.

Comment: does $a[0]["match_points"] and $a[0]["match_points"] help anything?

Comment: Which part of the error message is/was unclear to you?

Comment: @hakre the error message itself wasn't unclear. What was unclear was how to fix it.

Comment: Well I don't understand that. If the error message was clear, why was it unclear to fix it? What specifically was unclear for the fix by that error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your array is 3 dimensional but your sort is structured for a two dimensional array.

In php 5.3+ you can use usort with a closure

```
 usort($array, function($a, $b){return $a[0]["match_points"] - $b[0]["match_points"];});
```

Prior to 5.3 you have define a sorter function.

```
 function compMatchPoints($a, $b) {
      return $a[0]["match_points"] - $b[0]["match_points"];
 }
 usort($array, "compMatchPoints");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change all the $data variable to your array variable name

```
 $sortkeys = array();
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $sortkeys[] = $row[0]['match_points'];
    }
```

// sort $data according to $sortkeys and use SORT_DESC for descending order

```
array_multisort($sortKeys,SORT_DESC, $data, SORT_DESC);

echo "<pre>"
print_r($data);
die;
```